# CUDA missing host_defines.h centos 7

Tags: c++, cuda, centos, nvidia, nsight

I'm trying to compile some samples of the CUDA toolkit V6.5 in the environnement Nsight Eclipse edition 6.5 under centos 7.0.

My Nvidia Card is a Quadro K2000.

So my problem is when I try to build one of the samples (in toolkit cuda 6.5):
the following message appears in the Console and I don't know why :

```
make all 
Building target: ex3
Invoking: NVCC Linker
/usr/bin/nvcc --cudart static -L/usr/include/cuda --relocatable-device-code=false -gencode arch=compute_20,code=compute_20 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -link -o  "ex3"  ./src/matrixMulCUBLAS.o   -lcublas
/usr/bin/crt/link.stub:2:26: erreur fatale: host_defines.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include "host_defines.h"
                          ^
compilation terminée.
make: *** [ex3] Erreur 1




17:17:30 Build Finished (took 57ms)
```

Can anybody help me please ?

Comment: Have you supplied the correct include directories to compiler ? Isn't this `-L/usr/include/cuda` to be `-I/usr/include/cuda`

Comment: CUDA 6.5 does not list CentOS 7 as [an officially supported distro/version](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#system-requirements).

Comment: Yes, I have supplied in the propertie project of Nsight Eclipse in Build -> settings in Tool settings tab for NVCC linker the librairie /usr/include/cuda but it doesn't work better....

Comment: I don't know where is specified that CUDA 6.5 does not list CentOS 7 on nividia.com, do you think that with CUDA 6.0 it works better ? thanks

Comment: I gave you a link to it.  Click on the text "an officially supported distro/version" above, and study the table of supported versions in that "getting started" document.  Based on your question and answer, I think you have a corrupted install. The cuda installer does not put nvcc in /usr/bin/nvcc unless you tell it to.  I would suggest starting with a clean environment, and doing a proper install, following the getting started guide (same link as above), and using a supported distro.  If you want to use CentOS7, move to CUDA 7 RC.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your quick comments
I found the problem :
There were 2 places where there was NVCC exe

```
/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc and / usr / bin / nvcc
```

So, i did :

```
diff --side-by-side /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc /usr/bin/nvcc
```

=>files were differents

In addition, there was a nvcc.profile file in `/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/` for positioning environment variables.
And Nsight eclipse environnment uses `/usr/bin/nvcc`
  then
 Idid a symbolic link on the 2 files :

```
ln -s /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc nvcc
ln -s /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc.profile nvcc.profile
```

And now any project can build and run

However the solution is not completely good (because symbolic links)

And now I don't find how to configure my project in Nsight Eclipse edition 6.5 to use nvcc placed at the location `/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc`

I'm searching in the properties and  I don't find  where to do that.

Does anyone have an idea?
thanks

Comment: Just to add correction for my solution : symbolic link "ln -s /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc.profile" nvcc.profile doesn't work. First, you have to copy /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc.profile in /usr/bin. Then, you edit /usr/bin/nvcc.profile and replace "TOP              = $(_HERE_)/.." by "TOP              = /usr/local/cuda-6.5/" And now when you build Cuda project all is ok

Comment: None of this should be necessary.  You may be running down this path because you haven't made appropriate modfications to your `PATH` environment variable or followed the instructions in the [getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#abstract).

Comment: Can you give me the part of the instruction you think that I have not followed ? I read again all the instructions of getting started guide and I don't find where I can find my solution...

Comment: If you install CUDA and `nvcc` in `/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin` (the default location), then you should not have an `nvcc` *anywhere else*, and when you set the `PATH` environment variable properly, and invoke `nvcc`, it will use the `nvcc` in `/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin`, which will find the profile file (and all other files it needs) normally. Setting the `PATH` variable is described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#environment-setup), and the implication is that you don't (should not) have *another* `nvcc` somewhere else, *earlier* on your `PATH`.

Comment: Ok thanks, my install is ok, to sum up and fix my problem I just need to specified in Nsight Eclipse environnment that I want to use nvcc located in `/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin` (and I don't know why it use  `nvcc`  in `/usr/bin`). There must be a solution to specfied the `nvcc` that you want to use in Nsight Eclipse environnment.

Comment: It's using `nvcc` in `/usr/bin` because of the way your `PATH` environment variable is currently set up (`/usr/bin` appears before `/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin`) *and* the fact that you have an `nvcc` in both locations.  You really should not, and the installer will not put an `nvcc` in `/usr/bin` if you use a default install.  Your machine is messed up.  The way to sort it out is to remove any old traces of other CUDA toolkits.  If you use the default install location, and modify your `PATH` environment variable *correctly*, you can use multiple versions of `nvcc`, even with `nsight`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing these headers, installing **cuda-nvcc-10-0** or **nvidia-cuda-dev** package *might* help.